# Two DIVs inside DIV. How to auto-fill the space of parent DIV by second DIV?

Tags: css, html, height, autofill

Please visit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmand/HQwLG/) to see what I mean -

I have a parent DIV, within that there are two DIVs placed in vertical order.
The top DIV should have only the height of its content, whereas the bottom DIV should occupy all remain space of the parent DIV irrespective to content heights, and also shouldn't overlap the parent DIV.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div  class="inner-title">
        THIS IS MY TITLE
    </div>
    <div class="inner-content">
        CONTENT AREA
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body
{
height: 100%;
}

.outer
{
    background-color:blue;
    height: 80%;
}

.inner-title
{
    background-color:red;
}

.inner-content
{
background-color:yellow;
    height: auto;
}
```

In short, "inner-content" should occupy all remaining space of "outer" DIV, without overlapping.

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add  `display:table;` to parent div and  `display:table-row;` to child divs

And `height:0` to first child div. This takes auto height

```
    html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
.outer{
    background-color:blue;
    height: 80%; border:red solid 2px;
    display: table;
     width:100%
}
.inner-title{
    background-color:red;
    display:table-row; 
     width:100%
}
.inner-content{
    background-color:grey;
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

**[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/HQwLG/43/)**

Comment: @sowmya.. What about setting a min-height for the 2nd div??

Comment: Y do u need min-height. Op is expecting that div to occupy the entire space available

Comment: @Sowmya.. No.. No.. I jus had a doubt and so asked.. setting min-height to the remaining portion.. is it possible??

Comment: That is not really good in his question coz first div height is not fixed so

Comment: this looks a nice trick.. but one thing is that the height of first DIV should only be of its content size, where the second DIV should occupy rest of the space in parent DIV. Here it seems the first DIV is also taking much more space (height) than its contents

Comment: @Nirman that is coz I have added more content in first div to show sample. Check the updated answer now

Comment: thanks Sowmya... just checked this looks good in IE10, and Chrome.. but in Firefox it is showing two rows in equal height..

Comment: i suppose, the "display:table" and "display:table-row" are rendered differently in Chrome and Firefox!

Comment: thanks sowmya this worked for me.. your prompt responses have helped me a lot to work out this in reasonable time.

Comment: @Sowmya: Is there now a better flexbox-based solution? Or is display:table still the only way to do this?

Comment: @CarlosGaleano glad it helped

Answer (score 12):

A newer CSS way would be using **flexbox**

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;} html,body{height:100%;}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* or:   flex-flow: column wrap; */
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-fill { /* Add this class to the element you want to expand */
  flex: 1;  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-col">
    <div style="background:red;"> HEADER </div>
    <div class="flex-fill" style="background:yellow;"> CONTENT </div>
    <div style="background:red;"> FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: better solution than previous one, imho